# How to get TextField content when a "set" Button is mouseClicked in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

I have a TextView "EntNumT" and a "setB1" Button so that I may retrieve content of the TextView after clicking "set" Button with mouse and put in variable "entryNum".

```
public String setExfFileName(MouseEvent me) {
        entryNum = EntNumT.getText ().toString ();            
        System.out.println("Came to this function \n" +
                "Entry Num = "+ entryNum);  
        return entryNum;
}


public void setEntryNum(){                        
    setB1.setOnMouseClicked (this::setExfFileName)        
}
```

I just forgot a common point. How can I access returned string in method "setEntryNum"?

Comment: Is `setEntryNum` just called once for initialization? You can not access the return string currently but why don't you evaluate `EntNumT.getText().toString()` where you end up when the button is clicked?

Comment: @Smutje, `setEntryNum` is called during initialization which calls `setExfFileName` which actually evaluates `EntNumT.getText ().toString ()`. I am eager to know any better way to access TextField immediately after clicking a button.

Comment: You already access the field in `setExfFileName` when the button is clicked, but returning the value is pointless as a button click has no "return value" and rather performs an action which can be seen by the way you register the action at the button.